# Apache FOP: Inconsistent line breaks/word wrapping

Tags: xsl-fo, apache-fop

Under certain circumstances Apache FOP is not consistent with line breaks. Consider this example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
    <layout-master-set>
        <simple-page-master master-name="the-master-name" page-height="29.7cm" page-width="21.0cm" margin-top="1.21cm" margin-bottom=".8cm" margin-left="2.4cm"
                            margin-right="1.5cm">
            <region-body region-name="the-region-body"/>

        </simple-page-master>
    </layout-master-set>
    <page-sequence master-reference="the-master-name" force-page-count="no-force">
        <flow flow-name="the-region-body">
            <block border="1px solid red">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis
                dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis
                enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec a a a, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo.
                rhoncus. Maecenas tempus, tellus eget condimentum rhoncus, sem quam semper liberi a, sit amet adipiscing sem neque sed ipsum. Nam quam nunc,
                blandit vel, luctus pulvinaraxe, hendrerit id, lorem. Maecenas nec odio et ante tincidunt tempus. Donec vitae sapien ia a a a ut libero
                venenatis faucibus. Nullam quis ante. Etiam sit amet orci eget eros faucibusilem tincidunt. Duis leo. Sed fringilla mauris sit amet nibh. Donec
                sodales sagittis magna. Sed consequat, leo eget bibendum sodales, augue velit cursus nunc,
            </block>
        </flow>
    </page-sequence>
</root>
```

Result:

[image]

You can clearly see that the first highlighted "a"s are getting wrapped much sooner than the second ones. Not how I want it to be. What is going on?

Comment: Have you tried the current FOP 2.6? FOP uses the TeX (Knuth-Plass) line-breaking algorithm, which means that it does more than just fill each line as much as possible before moving to the next line (sometimes called 'greedy' line filling). However, AH Formatter also uses the Knuth-Plass algorithm (see https://www.antenna.co.jp/AHF/help/en/ahf-tech.html#line-breaking), and I couldn't make AH Formatter break like that around the 'a a a'.

Comment: Yes, I am using FOP 2.6 and it's the first time for me hearing about the TeX line break algorithm used in non-justified paragraphs.

Comment: IIRC spaces inside non-justified paragraphs are handled differently, so that the algorithm builds lines as similar in length as possible without stretching or shrinking spaces.

Comment: The TeX algorithm is described as providing minimum raggedness: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_wrap_and_word_wrap#Minimum_raggedness. Minimum raggedness is useful in unjustified text.

Comment: As the choice of the line breaks is ultimately a prerogative of the formatter (as long as it respects the constraints expressed with the formatting properties), and there is no evident bug in action, I'm inclined to vote to close this question.